# Oracle - Finding missing /non-joined records

Tags: sql, oracle, anti-join

I have an issue in Oracle 12 that is easiest explained with the traditional database design scenario of students, classes, and students taking classes called registrations.  I understand this model well.  I have a scenario where I need to get a COMPLETE list, of all students against ALL classes, and whether or not they are taking that class or not...

Lets use this table design here...

```
CREATE TABLE CLASSES 
(CLASSID  VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY,
CLASSNAME  VARCHAR2(25),
INSTRUCTOR VARCHAR2(25) );


CREATE TABLE STUDENTS
(STUDENTID  VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY,
STUDENTNAMENAME  VARCHAR2(25)
STUDY_MAJOR VARCHAR2(25) );

CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION
(
 CLASSID VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
 STUDENTID VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
 GRADE NUMBER(4,0), 
 CONSTRAINT "PK1" PRIMARY KEY ("CLASSID", "STUDENTID"),
 CONSTRAINT "FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("CLASSID") REFERENCES "CLASSES" ("CLASSID") ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "FK2" FOREIGN KEY ("STUDENTID") REFERENCES "EGR_MM"."STUDENTS" ("STUDENTID") ENABLE
 ) ;
```

So assume the following... 300 students, and 15 different classes...  and the REGISTRATION table will show how many students taking how many classes...  What I need is that info PLUS all the NON-TAKEN combinations...  i.e. I need a report (SQL statement) that shows ALL possible combinations... i.e. 300 x 15, and then whether that row exists in the registration table...so for example, the output should look like this...

```
STUDENTID   Class1_GRADE  Class2_Grade      Class3_Grade`       Class4_Grade
101         A               B                   Not Taking          A
102         C               Not Taking          Not Taking          Not Taking
****** THIS STUDENT NOT TAKING ANY CLASSES So NOT in the Registrations Table
103         Not Taking      Not Taking          Not Taking          Not Taking
```

This would work as well, and I can probably do a PIVOT to get the above listing.

```
STUDENTID   CLASSID  GRADE
101         Class1    A
101         Class2    B
101         Class3    Not Taking
101         Class4    A
...
102         Class1    C
102         Class2    Not Taking
102         Class3    Not Taking
102         Class4    Not Taking
...
103         Class1    Not Taking  // THIS STUDENT NOT TAKING ANY CLASSES
103         Class2    Not Taking
103         Class3    Not Taking
103         Class4    Not Taking
```

How do I fill in the missing data, i.e. the combination of students and classes NOT taken...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CROSS JOIN` the students and classes and then `LEFT OUTER JOIN` the registrations and then use `COALESCE` to get the `Not taken` value:

```sql
SELECT s.studentid,
       c.classid,
       COALESCE( TO_CHAR( r.grade ), 'Not taken' ) AS grade
FROM   students s
       CROSS JOIN classes c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN registration r
       ON ( s.studentid = r.studentid AND c.classid = r.classid )
```

Which, if you have the data:

```sql
INSERT INTO Classes
SELECT LEVEL,
       'Class' || LEVEL,
       'Instructor' || LEVEL
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3;

INSERT INTO Students
SELECT TO_CHAR( LEVEL, 'FM000' ),
       'Student' || LEVEL,
       'Major'
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

INSERT INTO Registration
SELECT 1, '001', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '002', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '003', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '001', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '001', 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Then it outputs:

> ```
> STUDENTID | CLASSID | GRADE    
> :-------- | :------ | :--------
> 001       | 1       | 4        
> 002       | 1       | 2        
> 003       | 1       | 5        
> 001       | 2       | 3        
> 001       | 3       | 1        
> 005       | 1       | Not taken
> 004       | 2       | Not taken
> 003       | 3       | Not taken
> 005       | 3       | Not taken
> 005       | 2       | Not taken
> 002       | 2       | Not taken
> 003       | 2       | Not taken
> 004       | 1       | Not taken
> 002       | 3       | Not taken
> 004       | 3       | Not taken
> ```

---

If you want to pivot it then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT s.studentid,
         c.classid,
         COALESCE( TO_CHAR( r.grade ), 'Not taken' ) AS grade
  FROM   students s
         CROSS JOIN classes c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN registration r
         ON ( s.studentid = r.studentid AND c.classid = r.classid )
)
PIVOT ( MAX( grade ) FOR classid IN (
  1 AS Class1,
  2 AS Class2,
  3 AS Class3
) )
ORDER BY StudentID
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> STUDENTID | CLASS1    | CLASS2    | CLASS3   
> :-------- | :-------- | :-------- | :--------
> 001       | 4         | 3         | 1        
> 002       | 2         | Not taken | Not taken
> 003       | 5         | Not taken | Not taken
> 004       | Not taken | Not taken | Not taken
> 005       | Not taken | Not taken | Not taken
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d22e74666db9ec3cfe90eb4e9f56baaf)*

Comment: Phenomonal answer... with nice example.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is just conditional aggregation:

```
select s.studentid,
       max(case when r.classid = 1 then r.grade end) as class1_grade,
       max(case when r.classid = 2 then r.grade end) as class2_grade,
       . . .
from students s left join
     registrations r
     on r.studentid = s.studentid;
```

You do have to list the columns explicitly.  To avoid that, you need dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`).

Getting the results with one grade per row is simpler.  Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the values:

```
select s.studentid, c.classid, r.grade
from students s cross join
     classes c left join
     registrations r
     on r.studentid = s.studentid and r.classid = c.classid;
```